# What is an interior of a domain of a function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

When explaining the continuity of convex functions, it says

> Let $f: E \rightarrow (-\infty, +\infty)$ be convex. Then $f$ is
>    continuous on the interior of its domain and, in fact, for any $x \in
>  int\ dom(f)$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ and $L>0$
>    such that for any $u,v\in U$, $f(u) - f(v) \le L ||u-v||_2$

Initially I thought $int\ dom(f)$ was the epigraph of $f$ but an epigraph isn't exactly a $dom(f)$. In addition, an interior point of a set is a point where it has an open neighborhood that is also in a set. But what is interior of a domain?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what book are you reading?

Comment: Here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bd38n4cuyxslh1e/online-learning-book.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The domain of $f$ is a particular set, and the interior of the domain of $f$ is just the interior of that set.  The rest of this answer explains what the interior of a set is, for completeness.

A picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

Let $S \subset \mathbb R^n$.  Then the interior of $S$ is the set of all points $x \in S$ such that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset S$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  Here $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the ball of radius $\epsilon$ at $x$:
$$
B(x,\epsilon) = \{ y \in \mathbb R^n \mid \| x - y \| < \epsilon \}.
$$

So, in other words, $x$ is in the interior of $S$ if and only if there exists a number $\epsilon > 0$ such that all points within $\epsilon$ of $x$ also belong to $S$.

Comment: Yes, that is the definition of an interior point of a set. But what is an interior of a domain? Are they the same thing?

Comment: @MoneyBall Yes, the domain of $f$ is a particular set, and the interior of the domain is just the interior of that set.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.