# what does the abbreviation $x \text{ int dom } f$ mean?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

What does the abbreviation $x \in \text{ int dom } f$ mean? Specifically, I know that dom means that x is in the domain of f, but what exactly is int short for?

Comment: Interior? ${}{}$

Comment: It means that $x$ is in the *interior* of the domain of $f$. The interior of a set is the subset of all elements which have an open ball around them in the set, or equivalently, the set minus its boundary. There's a good answer on this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2461240/1108193).

Comment: @Lemmon cheers that helps alot

Comment: Presumably it was $x \in ...$?

Comment: More usually in convex meanderings one sees $x \in \operatorname{ri} C$, the relative interior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a nonempty set and let $f : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ -\infty \right\} \cup \left\{ +\infty \right\}.$ Typically, in the field of convex analysis, $$ \textrm{dom} \, f = \left\{ x \in \mathcal{X} \, \middle| \, f (x) < +\infty \right\}; $$
note that (to be strict) $\textrm{dom} \, f$ does $\textit{not}$ correspond to the domain of $f$ when $f$ is viewed as a mapping (this would technically be $\mathcal{X}$ in our case). $\textrm{dom} \, f$ is sometimes called the $\textit{effective domain}$ of $f.$

Additionally, if $(\mathcal{X}, \mathsf{T})$ is a topological space and if $C$ is a subset of $\mathcal{X},$ $$\textrm{int} \, C \equiv \textrm{the largest open set contained in} \,\, C.$$
Thus,
$$x \in \textrm{int} \, \textrm{dom} \, f \iff x ~~\textrm{is an element of the largest open set contained in} ~~ \textrm{dom} \, f,$$
where we are assuming that $\mathcal{X}$ is a topological space, endowed with a topology, say $\mathsf{T}.$